# How to use DataGrip SQL formatter with compound WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, formatting, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

Which configuration can I set to get each clause of a WHERE statement to start on a new line? For example:

```sql
-- bad
select *
from table
where a = 1 and b = 2
```

```sql
-- good
select *
from table
where a = 1
  and b = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get each part of AND or OR condition on the next line, just set the following:

Queries / WHERE and HAVING clauses / Wrap elements ⟶ Chop

Comment: doesn't work if all the and conditions are in single line.
Works to align the conditions if they are already in new lines.